# Простейшая обработка данных Ajax.

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

Есть плагин jQuery.Form
Я отправляю данныe из формы php-скрипту.

$('#form').ajaxForm(
    function() {
        $("#form").clearForm();
            alert("Запись добавлена"); 
        }
    );

Все работает. Но сервер возвращает данные. Одно-единственное слово. Как мне записать ответ в переменную JavaScript? Знаю что как то через options->success, но не получается.

P.S. Как вариант - можно просто на jQuery. Без плагина.

Comment: function(data) { alert(data); попробуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Объект с опциями для плагина 
var options = { 
    target:     '#divToUpdate', 
    url:        'comment.php', 
    resetForm: true, // вместо вашего $('#myForm').clearForm()
    success:    function( data ) { 
        alert(data); 
    } 
};

// скармливаем их плагину
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.